# Nested For loop printing a multidimensional array arr[i][j]; surprising output of three numbers

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I added "break" in order to analyze the code. I'm pretty much a beginner, and 
trying really hard to understand why this code document writes "135 ".
As long as i  is smaller than arr.length, add one to i, that one is clear.
The second line refers to arr[i].length, I don't know what that is even after researching.
Maybe the length of arr[0], arr[1] and arr[2] = arr[i].length, so 2?
then the execution of the inner for loop I simply don't understand.

```
var arr = [
[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        document.write(arr[i][j]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: learn what `break` does - i.e. in your case it breaks your expectations (thank you, I'm here all week, please try the fish)

Comment: I know what it does, I don't understand the inner for loop. With or without break it doesn't change a thing for my understanding apparently.

Comment: @CodeLearner your understanding of `arr[i].length` is fine. Notice that `arr[i]` is just one of the inner arrays.

Comment: really? with break, you'll get 1,3,5 .. .without break you'll get 1,2,3,4,5,6 - that's "different" if you ask me

Comment: Stiil not understanding how the inner for loop works. Hopefully someone will chime in on that.

Comment: The inner loop says "print the element and then leave the inner loop early (for each element)", so only the first element ever gets printed.  The outer loops calls this on all three of the `[...]`, so you get the first from each -- 1,3,5.    And as for arr[i] --- it's the i-th element of arr.  arr[0] is [1,2], arr[1] is [3,4], arr[2] is [5,6].  The length of arr is 3, and the length of each element in arr (like [1,2]) is 2.

Answer (score 1):

So heres the flow:

```
var arr = [
  [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   // Inside this first loop we are dealing with an 
   // item in arr (e.g., [1,2])
   for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        // Inside this loop we are dealing with an item
        // from the previous loop (e.g, 1)
        // We write the one and then exit the inner loop
        // and move on to the next set of pairs.
        document.write(arr[i][j]);
        break;
   }
}
```

Sometimes it's easier to understand using variables. This is equivalent:

```
var arr = [
  [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var pair = arr[i];
    for (var j=0; j < pair.length; j++) {
        var num = pair[j];
        document.write(num);
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The break statement breaks the loop and continues executing the code after the loop. (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)

In this case, the 'break' only jumps out from the inner loop.

The outer loop will be executed 3 times.

You can simulate all the executions like this

```
i=0;
  j=0; j<arr[0].length;
    document.write(arr[0][0]);    // output 1
    break;                        // break inner loop

i=1;
  j=0; j<arr[1].length;
    document.write(arr[1][0]);    // output 3
    break;                        // break inner loop

i=2;
  j=0; j<arr[2].length;
    document.write(arr[2][0]);    // output 5
    break;                        // break inner loop
```

```